# How to change the total title on cart page in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, cart

[image]

I tried:

In vendor folder

```
 <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
           <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Tax/checkout/cart/totals/grand-total</item>
                 <item name="exclTaxLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total Excl. Tax</item>
                 <item name="inclTaxLabel" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total Incl. Tax</item>
            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total </item>
      </item>
     </item>
```

In my module Test\MyAccount\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>

  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">                                
                            <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                                       
                                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">You Pay</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: What is the title which you want to rename?

Comment: I want to rename Order Title to You Pay

Answer (score 1):

The cart summary used js layout.

In our custom layout,

*app/code/Vendor/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="block-totals" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Total Custom</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Tested on Magento 2.2.0 version.

Comment: I tried but file is not getting called from custom layout file.

Comment: Did you create a new module?

Comment: yes, I have created new module

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will work. Try to clear Magento Cache and Browser Cache.

Comment: Also, make sure your custom module works or not.

Comment: module is working fine and also cleared cache. Still not working.

Comment: <item name="grand-total" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>

Comment: above code is working but title is not getting renamed

Comment: Can you update your question with the screen shot which title you want to edit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67800/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-jassi).

Comment: overridding through theme we can change the title

Answer (score 0):

You can change Order Total to You Pay using language translate:
Install language pack.
`/app/i18n/vendor_name/languagepack/en_us.csv`(other language if used)

add string into this file:

```
"Order Total","You Pay"
```

then apply command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US <other_language>
```

You may require to run this after setup:upgrade command:

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
```

Contact me if not working!

Answer (score 0):

You can change Title 'Order Total' to 'You Pay' using language translation CSV.
Create language csv file as per your locale in `app/design/frontend/your_vendor_name/your_theme_name/i18n/en_US.csv`. Add `"Order Total","You Pay"` string in this file.

Answer (score 0):

In the below file you can change the total tile to your custom title

`vendor\magento\module-tax\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml`